# React component being re rendered

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create an app with Reactjs + Redux + React router but I'm having some problems that I don't understand what it's causing it. Most probably I'm not fully understand how it works.

When I update the store of Redux all the components get re rendered instead of the ones where the state it's used. That means that my api calls for example are running twice when I simple show a flash message. EG:

```
render() {
        const user = this.props.user;
        if( ! user || ! user.token  ) {
            return (<Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: "/login",
                    state: {from: this.props.location}
                }}
            />)
        }
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <Header {...this.props} />
                <FlashMessage message={this.props.flash.message} type={this.props.flash.msg_type} {...this.props}/>
                <div className="app-body">
                    <Sidebar {...this.props}/>
                    <main className="main">
                        <Breadcrumb />
                        <Container fluid>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/settings/permissions/add" name="Add Permission"
                                       component={() => <AddPermissionView {...this.props}/>}/>
                                <Route path="/settings/permissions/" name="Permissions"
                                       component={() => <ListPermissions {...this.props}/>}/>
                                <Route path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard"
                                       component={() => <Dashboard {...this.props}/>}/>
                                <Route path="/logout" name="Logout" component={() => <Redirect to="/login"/>}/>
                                <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard"/>
                            </Switch>
                        </Container>
                    </main>
                    <Aside />
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

So for example if I update the store for flash message, the Flashmessage compoenent gets rendered as it should, but also the Dashboard,sidebar,Header, etc.
I thought only the state that changed it's rendered again.

That means I need to use shouldComponentUpdate on every component I create to avoid that behaviour ?

Comment: It looks like if you update the store for flash message, then `this.props.flash.message` is getting updated. And since you're passing _all_ of `this.props` (including the updated one) to Dashboard, Sidebar, and Header, you should expect that they will update, too.

Comment: Also, what I don't understand here is, if the flash message is stored in redux state, why is it passed as a prop to FlashMessage? Shouldn't FlashMessage be connected to the redux store and receive the flash message through there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Render Prop and Component Prop inside of Route.

- When you use component instead of render the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component.
- if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render.
- This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component.

### Solution

Replace component props with the render prop in your routes.

```
    <Route path="/settings/permissions/add" name="Add Permission" render={() => <AddPermissionView {...this.props}/>}/>   
    <Route path="/settings/permissions/" name="Permissions"  render={() => <ListPermissions {...this.props}/>}/>
    <Route path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard"  render={() => <Dashboard {...this.props}/>}/>                
    <Route path="/logout" name="Logout"   render={() => <Redirect to="/login"/>}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, updates to the Redux Store cause application-wide re-renders, regardless of where the update was applied in the Store. In case of small applications, this behavior is typically not noticeable. However, as an application (and its state tree) grows, its performance can be easily hampered by that blanket "re-render every component" strategy.

Fortunately, there are solutions to this problem. I use **React Reselect**, which helps create **memoized selectors** that help localize renders to components whose state was affected, leaving everything else unchanged:

https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

I'd suggest reading through the text on the page, perhaps twice, [watching the video that's linked in the documentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Xwo5mVxDqI), and actually doing an example project to understand how Redux works naturally, and how Reselect gets rid of unnecessary component re-renders via memoized selectors.

Comment: "updates to the Redux Store cause application-wide re-renders, regardless of where the Store was updated" I don't believe this is quite true. Updates to the Redux Store will cause re-renders for exactly those components that depend on the things in the store that were updated

Comment: My understanding from the **Motivation for Memoized Selectors** section in the Reselect documentation (linked in answer) is that neither React nor Redux performs any heuristics to localize the effects of state mutations. My understanding is that any change in the Store is propagated to **all connected components**, the effect that OP is observing, and the reason that memoized selectors exist. If I'm mistaken, do you have any references or examples that illustrate the default behavior of React + Redux? I'd love to learn that and understand what problem exactly Reselect tries to solve.

Comment: I was unfamiliar with Reselect until reading your link, so I may be misunderstanding something here, but it seems to me like reselect is solving the problem of having some expansive value within your store on which you want to perform complex and/or expensive operations. It is true that any change on that value is propagated to all components connected to that value, but _only to those components_.

Comment: So a pattern in which you have some significant value that is updated all at once and which many different components are all referencing different pieces of is a pattern that it seems like reselect could improve upon, but that is not the situation in the original post; the OP has a single, isolated bit of state which it wants to update. It can do that just fine with default React + Redux, the problem is that the OP is passing that bit of state to things that don't need to depend on it